# GLPi does not import AD details but authenticates just fine

Tags: active-directory, rhel5, cname-record

I've installed an OCS/GLPI configuration using RHEL5. I've configured GLPI to authenticate to our AD, which it does, however, none of the AD user details appear after logging in. It will create the user account & just show a number. I am able to successfully see AD groups but not users. I verified the data request & response using wireshark & it is returning the proper syntax for rootdn & basedn yet no data will populate. We are a small company with few users so no elaborate OU's are present. To compound matters, the project is primarily in French which I unfortunately do not speak. I've tried posting to their boards but am getting very little response so I was hoping some of you might have some ideas that I could try ?

http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/OCS-GLPI-en

http://glpi-project.org/wiki/doku.php?id=en:ldap&s

http://glpi-project.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=14980

I've added a screenshot of my config [here](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/9868/glpi.jpg) 
http://img268.imageshack.us/my.php?image=glpi.jpg'>http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/9868/glpi.jpg' border='0' alt='Image Hosted by ImageShack.us'/>

I'm also using the latest version 0.71.5, downloaded 5/11/09

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please compare your LDAP config to the following screenshot, make sure the AD->GLPI mappings are the same. By default you also have to use an authenticated AD user account to retrieve info from AD.

http://img241.imageshack.us/img241/1590/glpisetup.jpg

I am currently on version 0.71.5. I have also tried project forums in the past, but they were of not help. They claim they will start documenting everything in English once they have more English-speaking developers...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to enter "samaccountname" (in the login field) all in lower case rather than being case sensitive like all the other fields. You then must use an AD account (in the rootdn field) to retrieve the details as shown in the other screen shots.